# CSRF Protection on static pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, security, csrf, csrf-protection

I have a static site which has forms. The forms submits to a Rails endpoint which captures the submitted data. The static site and the Rails endpoint are on the same domain, on different subdomains and all traffic is completely on HTTPS.

I understand how Rails CSRF works for server generated forms. But in my case, these forms are on static HTML pages. I understand all request headers can be faked, so can't rely on that.

If a strong solution is not possible for this scenario then my last option would be to move to server generated forms (which I want to avoid for now).

Any suggestions on a good approach to this would be most welcome. Or any pointers to a system or a library which already does this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the [CSRF prevention cheat sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

There are two static methods that can be used.

1)Use JavaScript to fetch the token and rewrite the static HTML page to include the nonce.

2)[Check the Referer and Origin headers](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Checking_The_Referer_Header)

Comment: On 2 > Is it not possible to spoof the REFERER header of an HTTPS POST request - making it less secure?

Comment: The CSRF cheat cheat sheet says: Although it is trivial to spoof the referer header on your own browser, it is impossible to do so in a CSRF attack. - I don't quite understand this.

Comment: @Akshay Rawat the point of CSRF is that you are forging a request inside the confines of your victims browser.  The referer,  origin and other headers can never be modfied.  Using Flash some headers can be changed,  but the Referer and Origin are always off limits.